# How to run python script from remote?

Tags: terminal, ssh, python

I do have a python script which I am using locally in Terminal, works great. It makes use of Apple's iCloud / credentials so it must be run on my Mac.
Now I need to run the script from remote (a webserver) and parse / save the output of it.

I have thought to activate Apache and PHP on my Mac, but I don't want to give access to everyone either, so this is maybe not the best.

I have tried to open SSH access, I can login from my local network, but not from remote – guess I'd need some kind of port forwarding? There seems to be IP6 only, so I don't know how to do this. And I am not sure if this is the way to go anyway.

Does anyone have an idea how to? Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Port forwarding needs to be set on the router.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do that this round-about is the way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to access from outside your network, you need to do a port forward or something similar. If you want to run a command from another external location, you can run a command similar to the following:

```
ssh username@your_server_ip 'your_command_here'
```

I'd start by verifying remote ssh access, then fine tune your command. Good luck.

Comment: thank you, works. I still have to find out how to "bypass" the password though.

Comment: Use either an SSH public key or go whole hog and set up ansible.

Comment: ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id: now it works without password prompt. thank you all!